# How to keep the bootstrap panel open on button click in body

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsable panel in `bootstrap css` and have a `button` inside the panel body

On click of that button i open a bootstrap modal

Now the problem i am having is whenever i click on the button it opens the modal fine but it closes the panel

I want to keep the panel open on click of the button

I already tried `e.preventdefault()`

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse0" class="panel panel-default panel-style row event-row" id="panel0">
    <div id="event-title" class="panel-heading event-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">test</h4>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" id="5" onclick="checkinEvent(this)" class="checkin-btn btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i
                    id="i5" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Check in
            </button>
            <span class="label label-default badge-round pull-right label-checkin">1 </span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div><p>test<strong>&nbsp;description</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm location-btn center-block"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>00 Piter Street, New South Wales,
                    Australia
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" class="panel panel-default panel-style row event-row collapsed"
     id="panel1" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="event-title" class="panel-heading event-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">show jumping test 1</h4>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" id="10" onclick="checkinEvent(this)" class="checkin-btn btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i
                    id="i10" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Check in
            </button>
            <span class="label label-default badge-round pull-right label-checkin">1 </span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div><p><strong>This is a very long description written<span id="restOfArticle" style="display:none"> just to test the word wrap and make it more compatible with the mobile screen. ThisIsAVeryVeryLongWordWrittenToTestWordWrapCSSIHopeItWorks</span></strong>
                </p>
                <a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this,&quot;restOfArticle&quot;)">..Read more</a></div>
            <div>
                <button id="10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm location-btn center-block"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>500 Piter Street, New South Wales,
                    Australia
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/R6EAW/2453/).. It not perfect but as you can see if i click on the button it closes the panel...

I want to prevent the panel from closing
What else can i do to keep the panel open???

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your whole HTML?

Comment: Any chance you could create a codepen with the problem?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I am doing it and will update the code soon but it will take time as i am using a lot of javascript css and action code in the panel

Comment: Thanks @MikeRoss I managed to set my own up and I see the problem. Just working on a fix at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not only clicking on the button with modal, panel close even when you click in the panel-body.

Move `data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse0"` to the panel-heading and your panel will open and close only when you click on the heading (now you have this on the div with class panel and it causes your issue).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the code and follow the following code about Accordion Bootstrap. Here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion